# Can i set up Mysql to auto-partition?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I want to partition a very large table. As the business is growing, partitioning by date isn't really that good because each year the partitions get bigger and bigger. What I'd really like is a partition for every 10 million records.

The Mysql manual show this simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
id INT NOT NULL,
fname VARCHAR(30),
lname VARCHAR(30),
hired DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
separated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
job_code INT NOT NULL,
store_id INT NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (store_id) (
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (16),
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

But this means that everything larger than 16 and less than MAXVALUE gets thrown in the last partition. Is there a way to auto-generate a new partition every  interval (in my case, 10 million records) so I won't have to keep modifying an active database? I am running Mysql 5.5

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my actual table

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
`row_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`filename` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`unit_num` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`string` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`voltage` float(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`impedance` float(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`amb` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`ripple_v` float(8,6) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`,`filename`,`string`,`unit_num`),
 KEY `index1` (`filename`),
 KEY `index2` (`timestamp`),
 KEY `index3` (`timestamp`,`filename`,`string`),
 KEY `index4` (`filename`,`unit_num`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=690892041 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and an example query for the graph is...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') as mytime,voltage,impedance,amb,ripple_v,unit_num 
FROM my_table WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB('2015-07-31 00:05:59', INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
AND filename = 'dlrphx10s320upsab3' and unit_num='5' and string='2'ORDER BY timestamp asc;
```

Here is the explain for the query...

```
mysql> explain SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') as mytime,voltage,impedance,amb,ripple_v,unit_num FROM my_table WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB('2015-07-31 00:05:59', INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND filename = 'dlrphx10s320upsab3' and unit_num='5' and string='2'ORDER BY timestamp asc;
+----+-------------+------------+------+-------------------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys           | key    | key_len | ref         | rows  | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+------+-------------------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | unit_tarma | ref  | timestamp,index3,index4 | index4 | 58      | const,const | 13440 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+------------+------+-------------------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your name fields are hard-capped at thirty characters? Time to [re-evaluate your assumptions](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Also as far as I know adding a `PARTITION` requires altering the schema, but someone else should confirm this.

Comment: You can create stored procedure which alter your table to create new partition as per your requirement. After creating proc you can use mysql event scheduler which executes the procedure after specific time interval. By this you can implement dynamic auto partitioning.

Comment: LOL tadman. I said that was the example provided by Mysql. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This answer is directed at the schema and SELECT.)

Since you anticipate millions of rows, first I want to point out some improvements to the schema.

- `FLOAT(m,n)` is usually the 'wrong' thing to do because it leads to two roundings.  Either use plain `FLOAT` (which seems 'right' for metrics like voltage) or use `DECIMAL(m,n)`.  `FLOAT` is 4 bytes; in the cases given, `DECIMAL` would be 3 or 4 bytes.
- When you have both `INDEX(a)` and `INDEX(a,b)`, the former is unnecessary since the latter can cover for such.  You have 3 unnecessary KEYs.  This slows down `INSERTs`.
- `INT(3)` -- Are you saying a "3-digit number"?  If so consider `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (values 0..255) for 1 byte instead of `INT` for 4 bytes.  This will save many MB of disk space, hence speed.  (See also `SMALLINT`, etc, and `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`.)
- If `filename` is repeated a lot, you may want to "normalize" it.  This would save many MB.
- Use `NOT NULL` unless you need `NULL` for something.
- `AUTO_INCREMENT=690892041` implies that you are about 1/3 of the way to disaster with `id`, which will top out at about 2 billion.  Do you use `id` for anything?  Getting rid of the column would avoid the issue; and change the `UNIQUE KEY` to `PRIMARY KEY`.  (If you do need `id`, let's talk further.)
- `ENGINE=MyISAM` -- Switching has some ramifications, both favorable and unfavorable.  The table would become 2-3 times as big.  The 'right' choice of `PRIMARY KEY` would further speed up *this* `SELECT` significantly.  (And may or may not slow down other `SELECTs`.)

A note on the `SELECT`:  Since `string` and `unit_num` are constants in the query, the last two fields of `ORDER BY timestamp asc, string asc, unit_num asc` are unnecessary.  If they are relevant for reasons not apparent in the `SELECT`, then my advice may be incomplete.

This

```
WHERE filename = 'foobar'
  AND unit_num='40'
  AND string='2' 
  AND timestamp >= ...
```

is optimally handled by `INDEX(filename, unit_name, string, timestamp)`.  The order of the columns is not important *except* that `timestamp` needs to be *last*.  Rearranging the current `UNIQUE` key, you give you the optimal index.  (Meanwhile, none of the indexes is very good for this `SELECT`.)  Making it the `PRIMARY KEY` and the table InnoDB would make it even faster.

Partitioning?  No advantage.  Not for performance; not for anything else you have mentioned.  A common use for partitioning is for purging 'old'.  If you intend to do such, let's talk further.

In huge tables it is best to look at all the important `SELECTs` simultaneously so that we don't speed up one while demolishing the speed of others.  It *may* even turn out that partitioning helps in this kind of tradeoff.

Comment: This graph query I am doing is only one of hundreds of other queries being done on this table, hence, the other indexes. 2 billion records? I thought Mysql got rid of that limitation? Can it not support a full INT 11 auto-increment? Part of the weak design here is that this table is 12 years old. For example, filename is legacy. It could be a long int and be much faster to index. I am just trying to find a way to increase the speed of my queries. Will partitioning help? As far as row_id, that again is legacy and there is a ton of code that uses it for queries and edits.

Comment: The `(11)` is the maximum number of characters needed to display the value (a minus, plus 10 digits).  It does _not_ control how big the number can be.  `INT(2)` and `INT(99)` are identical.

Comment: Partitioning will _not_ help for _this_ `SELECT` after you add the `INDEX` I suggested.  Partitioning _may_ help other queries, but it is unlikely.  In [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint), I list the only 4 cases where partitioning is beneficial (that I have found).

Comment: `INT SIGNED` is a signed 32-bit number that occupies 4 bytes, hence a 2 billion (2^32-1) max value. `INT UNSIGNED` is a 32-bit number that occupies 4 bytes, hence a 4-billion max value. `BIGINT` is 8 bytes (a huge limit).  (I re-inserted this comment to fix a serious typo.)

Comment: I read your blog and I thought that the sheer number of records here made partitioning beneficial? I will have over 1 billion records soon.

Comment: Nope.  For example:  A "point query" in a billion-row table without partitioning will drill down about 5 levels of BTree.  With partitioning, it picks the partition (which takes some effort), then drills down about 4 levels.  Similar effort.  Given `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT` I can make specific arguments that partitioning does or does not help any.

Comment: Notice how the use cases generally do not rely just on partitioning, but rather require code changes (#1: `DROP` instead of `DELETE`).  I am anxiously awaiting a 5th use case.  (But I've been waiting several years.)

Comment: For your one `SELECT`, and with the index I suggested, the entries needed from the index are consecutive -- that's as good as it can get.  And that is the case whether the table is partitioned or not.  While scanning the, say, 10K rows of the index, it needs to reach into the "data" for `voltage`, etc.  This could be 10K _random_ disk hits.  Now it is hard to predict how many of them will be cached, and whether more will be cached if the query is pruned down to a single partition.  _Maybe_ it will be better.

Comment: For billion-row tables, performance is all about "minimizing the number of disk hits".

Comment: Thanks Rick. I am tweaking it now. Takes forever to re-index a 600M row table. LOL

Comment: I added my query above. I re-arranged it to take advantage of the order of the unique key, and it returns 371 rows but takes 30 seconds. This is still excessive I think? Any other suggestions?

Comment: "Takes forever to re-index" -- an argument for updating to 5.6 with its `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`.

Comment: Let's see the `EXPLAIN` for that 30-second query.

Comment: Added to original post. BTW, instead of re-indexing, I changed the order in my query to match the unique key called 'timestamp'. This is running on a test machine, dedicated MYSQL only, 100GB RAM, 12 cores. Percona optimized my.cnf.

Answer (score 0):

First, I must ask what benefit Partitioning gives you?  Is there some query that runs faster because of it?

There is no auto-partitioning.

Instead, you should have a job that runs every day and it counts the number of rows in the 'last active' partition to see if it is about 10M.  If so, add another partition.

I recommend keeping the "last" partition (the one with `MAXVALUE`) empty.  That way you can `REORGANIZE PARTITION` to split it into two empty partitions with essentially zero overhead.  And I recommend that instead of `ADD PARTITION` because you might slip up and put something in the last partition.

It is unclear what will trigger 10M.  Are there multiple rows for each store_id?  And are there new rows coming in for each store?  If so, then partitioning on store_id since all partitions will be growing all the time.

OK, so store_id was just a lame example from the reference manual.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can talk concrete, not hand-waving.  There are simply too many ways to take this task.

What is the activity?

If you mostly hit the "recent" partition(s), then an uneven distribution may be warrantied -- periodically add a new partition and combine an adjacent pair of old partitions.  (I did this successfully in one system.)

If you will be purging "old" data, then clearly you need to use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` and use `DROP PARTITION` plus `REORGANIZE PARTITION`.

And there are lots of other scenarios.  But I know of only 4 scenarios where Partitioning provides any performance benefit.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Comment: I have over 600M rows and I generally extract 100K at a time for graphs. 90% of the time the 100K come from somewhere in the last 50M rows. Would that be faster?

Comment: It depends.  I don't see any indexes -- they are vital to performance.  What `SELECT` do you use?  From that, I should be able to recommend an `INDEX` and say whether partitioning would help.

Comment: Also...  Where does `id` come from?  Is some combination of columns 'unique' within this table?

Comment: The above example is not the actual table. I added the results of show create table for my table.